# ¿Por qué este código devuelve la clase madre y no la hija?

Tags: java, herencia, polimorfismo

¿Por qué el siguiente código devuelve?

```
Yeti....
```

La variable de la clase madre y la función de la clase hija.

```
class Monstre {
        String nom= "Yeti";
        String faSoroll() { return "roar";}
}

class Vampir extends Monstre {
        String nom= "Dracul";
        String faSoroll() { return "....";}
}

class VanHelsing {
        void cercaMonstres() {
                Monstre a = new Vampir();
                System.out.println(a.nom + a.faSoroll());
        }

        public static void main (String[] args) {
                new VanHelsing().cercaMonstres();
        }
}
```

La clase `Vampir` hereda de `Monstre`, pero en lugar de devolver "Dracul...." me está devolviendo "Yeti..." perteneciente a la clase madre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La invocación polimórfica de métodos aplica solamente sobre métodos de instancia. En tiempo de ejecución lo único que se selecciona dinamicamente sobre el objeto actual son los métodos de instancia, no los métodos estáticos, no las variables de instancia. **Solamente los métodos sobreescritos de la instancia se invocan dinamicamente en tiempo de ejecución**.

Dicho esto, y espero no haber aburrido con tanta repetición, es fácil ver por qué se muestra lo que se muestra.

Instancias `VanHelsing` y llamas `cercaMonsters`.
Este método crea una variable de tipo `Monstre` a la que asigna valor de la instancia de `Vampir`. Todo bien, hay herencia. Lo que te confunde es `a.nom`, esto es de `Monstre` y `faSoroll` es de `Vampir`. Pero es correcto.

Lee otra vez el primer párrafo y te recomiendo algún libre de polimorfismo - uno de mis favoritos es *OCA & OCP Java SE 7 Programmer I & II Study Guide (Exams 1Z0-803 & 1Z0-804)* de Kathy Sierra y Bert Bates.

Comment: Aparte de lo que dices hay un error en el modelo de datos. La clase `Vampir` no debería tener una propiedad `nom`. Precisamente el ejemplo  muestra que ella es capaz de heredar esa propiedad de la clase padre, por tanto, ¿qué sentido tiene dar a la clase hija una propiedad que ya tiene la clase padre? Esto es contradictorio desde el punto de vista de la herencia.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón del mundo. Pero habiendo "heredado" la propiedad es confuso. Entiendo que por esto es la pregunta de "por qué muestra esto y no el otro". A lo mejor los diseñadores de java no deberían permitir que se sobreescriban campos de la instancia. Si esto fuese error de compilación (que no lo es ni debe serlo porque no entra en conflicto con el concepto herencia) no tendríamos estos problemas.